# Django import export in admin for auth model user

Tags: django

I want to add import export function for the table django.contrib.auth.models User in admin panel so i can add available user list in database. for this i'm trying this code-

```py
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
    from import_export import resources

    admin.site.unregister(User)
    @admin.site.register(User)
    class UserAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
        pass
```

but im getting error like

```
 class UserAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

how can i add emport export function to User table

Comment: I think you are missing **resource_class**, which is mention in package doc.

Answer (score 1):

The decorator for registering a `ModelAdmin` class is [`admin.register`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#the-register-decorator) not `admin.site.register`

```
@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    pass
```